# Chef: client authentication issue with vagrant

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use `chef_client` as provisioner. Currently, I'm getting this message:

```
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "vagrant-3ccfff14"
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: Authentication Error:
==> default: ---------------------
==> default: Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).
==> default:
==> default: Server Response:
==> default: ----------------
==> default: Invalid signature for user or client 'living-digital-validator'
==> default:
==> default: Relevant Config Settings:
==> default: -------------------------
==> default: chef_server_url         "https://api.chef.io/..."
==> default: validation_client_name  "living-digital-validator"
==> default: validation_key          "/tmp/vagrant-chef/validation.pem"
==> default:
==> default: If these settings are correct, your validation_key may be invalid.
==> default:
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
==> default:
```

It's trying to pick `validation_key` as `"/tmp/vagrant-chef/validation.pem"` instead of picking `living.pem` file I've set on `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe 'custom_recipe'
    chef.chef_server_url = 'https://api.chef.io/...'
    chef.validation_key_path = 'living.pem'
    chef.validation_client_name = 'living-digital-validator'
end
```

I'm using an account I've just created on Chef Server as cloud (Chef Manage).

Why is it picking a `pem` instead of I've set on `Vagranfile`?

I've created a `knife.rb` file this content:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "living"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/living.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/..."
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

and then I've performed `knife ssl check`:

```
Connecting to host api.chef.io:443
Successfully verified certificates from `api.chef.io'
```

Comment: `chef.validation_key_path = 'living.pem'` <= maybe try to specify a full path ? Vagrant will copy into the created VM all necessary files under `/tmp/vagrant-chef` and run chef from there, it is not copying the correct key as you didn't specify a full path as far as I can tell here.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai. I tested it before setting full path. Nevertheless, it keeps failing (the message is the same). A `validation.pem` file is copied in `temp/vagrant-chef`...

Comment: I mean this path is relative to your host machine, use a full path of your actual location for this file, not into the VM machine.

Comment: Yes, yes. I've tried setting the full path of my hosted `living.pem`. So, I'm working in a windows machine and I've tried with `D:\projects\living\vagrant\production\centos\living.pem`. This `living.pem` file is located where `Vagrantfile` is located.

Comment: I meant that a `validation.pem` file is copied into `/tmp/vagrant-chef` with the contents of `living.pem`. It's possible it's an issue related with the `validation_client_name`?

Comment: Seems so, as you're using 'living' as user name in your knife.rb and not 'living-digital-validator'. I've no access to your chef organization to confirm or infirm... did you take the tutorials athttps://learn.chef.io ? (if not you really should to get a better overview)

Comment: I'm realizing I'm not really providing a username. I thought `validation_client_name` stant for providing a client validator. In fact, I don't quite figure out what's a `validator`. How should I provide the username?

Comment: the validator client name is the one for who the key has been created, it's a special client which can create other clients and nodes object and linked them together. Really, take the time to go through the tutorials, it's all explained.

Answer (score 0):

This means either your validation client name or key (likely the latter) is incorrect. You can reset the key through the Chef Web UI or `knife client rekey`.